# SQL String not fetching data

Tags: sql-server, razor

I'm using sql server compact 4 and i have run into a little snag. I have a table named Counter where i store some information 0-2 and it checks the todays date in that table, grabs the CounterValue and put them into one variable each 0,1,2 and present itself as a counter. The next day the new data will have a new date and will present the same values in each variable.

So far so good, if i run the SQL query as follows

```
SELECT * FROM Counter WHERE Dateis = '21-05-2014'
```

It present the correct values but when i try the Select from Razor it nothing is executed and it's driving me bonkers.

```
var DateNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
var CaseCounter = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Counter WHERE Dateis ='DateNow'");
```

DateNow has the value of 21-05-2014, the same as the sql query i tested have but it does nothing. No data is presented. If i remove the WHERE data will be displayed but then i displays all Dates data and not the current date.

Am i missing something here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not using the `DateNow` !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually patch in the value of the variable, rather than the name of the variable:

```
var DateNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
var CaseCounter = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Counter WHERE Dateis = '" + DateNow + "'");
```

Your original code is literally submitting this command to the DB:

```
SELECT * FROM Counter WHERE Dateis = 'DateNow'
```

So instead you need to close the string with the double-quote, then a concatenation operator (the + ) and then your variable, before concatenating the closing quote.

Comment: Ah Sweet! I did not know that, thanks a bunch for helping me out there it was driving me mad to be frank. Now i can get on tackling the other problems i have. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Yep im on it but it's a 10 min timer on the Correct Solution to be checked.